# baseURL is changing after build_site()

Tags: r, rstudio, hugo, blogdown

When using Academic theme and building using blogdown in Rstudio, the baseurl is not preserved. My menu items link to https://heima.hafro.is/#experience instead of [https://heima.hafro.is/~jim/#experience](https://heima.hafro.is/%7Ejim/#experience)
I have tried

```
baseURL: https://heima.hafro.is/~jim/
```

and

```
baseURL: "https://heima.hafro.is/~jim/"
```

in my config.yaml
Everything works when I use serve_site()
This site used to build a few months ago without problems, but have updated packages, and something has broke. Tried rolling back blogdown but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, instead of giving baseURL in the config.yaml, specify it when building the site i.e.

```
blogdown::build_site(baseURL = "https://heima.hafro.is/~jim/")
```